# Stuck on reboot after Ubuntu 23.04 install

Tags: boot, 23.04

After upgrading from Ubuntu 22.10 to Ubuntu 23.04, the boot gets stuck on 2 processes:

1. Job gpu-manager.service/start
2. Job plymouth-quit-wait.service/start

   [image]

Also earlier in the boot shows "Dependency failed for" a series of SSSD services.

[image]

The computer is an Acer Predator Helios with a SSD. What should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had the same issue. It turned out to be a bug with the **nvidia-driver-470** package currently installed. I installed **nvidia-driver-515** instead and the new Lunar boot process worked flawlessly. Here are the steps:

1. Boot into recovery mode to view the GNU GRUB menu: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode
2. Choose to boot with Linux kernel 5.19.0 instead of Linux kernel 6.2.0. I was able to successfully boot up and open a terminal with the older 5.19.0 kernel.
3. Run the `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515` command to install the different Nvidia driver version.
4. Reboot to confirm that everything now works with the default kernel 6.2.0 boot process.

Comment: Overall the above worked, but I was already using the 510 driver so I updated to the 525 driver (listed as “tested” in Software & Updates - Additional Drivers). 

Thanks for the tip. 

PS - I hadn’t caught that “Esc” brings up the recovery menu in UEFI, not “Shift” *facepalm*

Comment: Thanks for the tip facepalming myself! Pressed `Esc` too for crying out loud.

Comment: Driver 510 not compatible with the new kernel, and not automatically upgraded, shouldn’t that be considered as a bug?

Answer (score 3):

After upgrading Xubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 I've got stuck in normal boot and also in recovery boot. Booting with the old kernel 5.19.0-40 was still working. The Nvidia driver version was at 510.108.03.

I upgraded the Nvidia driver to 515.105.01 using:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515
```

and rebooted. Then normal boot was working again.

Answer (score 2):

Dale Kube's answer (and Matthew H's comment) are spot-on.

A couple of things to note for me:

1. I was already at v510, and had to install nvidia-driver-525
2. System reboot got stuck waiting for the old nvidia driver to unload (systemd-udev).

I eventually used the power button to shut off the PC. This hasn't recurred since.

Answer (score 1):

Running

```bash
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
```

fixed it for me. It actually install `nvidia-driver-530`. But now everything is fine. :-)

Comment: I have the same problem. Every time I upgrade from Ubuntu 22.10 to 23.04 my workstation won't boot. All I get is a message about Kernel Panic.

I have tried several times with a clean 22.10 install I can't even boot into recovery mode so can't play with drivers.

Grateful for your advice